# Convert .ods document to .docx document

Tags: libreoffice, convert, microsoft-office, format-conversion

I want to convert a LibreOffice document to an MSWord document but I haven't found any tool for the conversion.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: sorry?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039699/converting-ods-to-docx-file

Comment: -1 for obviously doubleposting, not providing any clarification of whether you indeed have an ods or an odt document and not indicating that you have put any research effort into this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite useful tool to convert `.odt` files (assuming your goal is converting `.odt` instead of `.ods` to `.docx`) - it's called LibreOffice. LO has a command line interface, allowing for file conversions without opening the `.odt` file in the LO GUI.

Here's an extract showing the required command line parameter `--convert-to`` (for LibreOffice 5.1.6):

```
$ soffice -h
LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 10m0(Build:2)

Usage: soffice [options] [documents...]

Options:

(...) 

--convert-to output_file_extension[:output_filter_name[:output_filter_options]] [--outdir output_dir] files
      Batch convert files (implies --headless).
      If --outdir is not specified then current working dir is used as output_dir.
      Eg. --convert-to pdf *.doc
          --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /home/user *.doc
          --convert-to "html:XHTML Writer File:UTF8" *.doc
          --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" *.doc

(...)

Remaining arguments will be treated as filenames or URLs of documents to open.
```

Just use `docx` as output filter name.

So,

```
soffice --convert-to docx file.odt
```

would convert the file `file.odt` to `file.docx` (the parameter `--headless` isn't required any more).

Important: the command line command works only if there's no other LO instance running. So, make sure to exit LO before issuing the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from Libre Office. When you do a Save-As, there are only 2 options. All formats or ODF. Only when you click on All formats, does it populate the dropdownbox with all the format.